# How am i getting "Exception thrown error" in c

Tags: c

I wrote this code in codelite and visual studio.This works in Codelite but I am getting an error in visual studio.In the beginning its is working but when I write the name I am getting an exception error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char name[20];
    printf_s("Enter your name:");
    scanf_s("%s",name);
    printf_s("Nice to meet you %s",name);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
```

Comment: What is `isim`?

Comment: Welcome to SO. That code cannot work in any environment as it doesn't even contain any `main` function. Please only show compileable code. Also there are no exceptions in C. Where do you get such a message and what exactly does the message say?

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: How long is your name?

Comment: @Gerhardh: There are environments that do not require a `main` routine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scanf_s("%s", isim);
```

This line is wrong. You have to specify the buffer size after the pointer to the buffer when you are using [`scanf_s()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=msvc-160).

Also don't forget to

- Include all required headers
- Define all variables used
- Initialize all variables before reading

It should be like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char isim[1024]; /* declare variables to use */
    char name[20] = "name"; /* initialize variables to read */
    printf_s("Enter your name:");
    scanf_s("%s", isim, (unsigned)_countof(isim)); /* specify the buffer size */
    printf_s("Nice to meet you %s",name);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I wrote that visual studio but i record the file as c.

Comment: @n_stckwf Your fix is incomplete because it doesn't contain any function definition.

Comment: thank you when I add the buffer size it is fixed.